# GCP: "Compute Engine not ready"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to start my instance I'm Getting the error message:

> "Starting VM instance "proj-p100-vm" failed. Error: Google Compute
>   Engine is not ready for use yet in the project. It may take several
>   minutes if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled, or if this is
>   the first time you use Google Compute Engine in the project."

Have waited an hour and it still doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled google compute engine in your gcp project?

Comment: Yes. There might be an outage right now: https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: As I read the outage is in the us-east, you might want to try different zone?

Comment: Outage is over and this still doesn't work. Maybe I need to re-enable the compute engine?

Comment: Has your project been associated with a billing account? You can't create money-spending resources (like an instance) until you do that.

Comment: Yes it has, although I changed which account it was linked to. Maybe that is the problem? (They are tied to the same credit card though!)

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to know that there was a Cloud Console Incident #19003 [1] reported via Google Cloud Status Dashboard [2] wherein users received a "failed to load" error message when attempted to list resources like Compute Engine instances etc.

Hope this helps.

[1] https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19003

[2] https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: My problem persists after the outage.

Comment: Have you tried disabling and re-enabling the Google Compute Engine API in the Developers Console?

Comment: If I do that I get "Error Disabling Api
[Could not turn off service, as it still has resources in use.] with failed services [compute.googleapis.com]"

Comment: It seems that this issue can't be resolved without asking sensitive information, I'd suggest to create support case in your GCP and select the project for which you'd like to open a support case.